# Get method that can return more than one type using template

Tags: c++, templates

Having multiple `get` methods for multiple private members makes a class quite messy. I would like to implement a single `get` method that is able to return whichever member I need.

```
enum TYPE {INT, DOUBLE, DOUBLE2, STRING};

class Foo {
int i     = 1;
double d  = 2.5;
double d2 = 6.0;
string s  = "string";

public:

template<typename T>
T get(TYPE type) {
    switch (type) {
    case INT:
        return i;
    case DOUBLE:
        return d;
    case DOUBLE2:
        return d2;
    case STRING:
        return s;
    }
}
```

The method would then be used like this:

```
Foo foo;
int integer = foo.get<int>(INT);
double d2   = foo.get<double>(DOUBLE2);
```

Why won't it compile?

Comment: While there is a way to make it compile, I urge you not go this road. Best you can do in given scenario is to make your members public and drop getters/setters altogether.

Comment: @SergeyA Well, the example is just an example - a stupid one, just to give the idea of what I want to achieve. I would like to implement something similar in a class where making some of the members private actually makes sense, and using getters for these members is necessary. Why do you think using a single `get` method for all private members that need a getter is a bad idea?

Comment: It would seem like you'd probably want to have a look at [std::tuple](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple)…

Comment: @Chriss555888 unless you implement something like `std::tuple`, you better have meaningful names.

Comment: @SergeyA  And I am very curious why it won't compile as it is now. I don't work with templates very often, so I possibly got something wrong.

Comment: It most likely doesn't compile because `string` (whatever that may be exactly) most likely cannot be converted to `int` or `double`. Thus, instantiating `get<T>` with either of those types as `T` will not lead to a valid function because `return s;` won't fly when the return type is not `string` (or something that string can be converted to)…

Comment: imho already having getters for private members is the mess. Doesnt really matter how many of them or what type. Getters arent really about encapsulation but about trying to pretend there was encapsulation.

Comment: interfaces should be about interactions of objects. Instead of provide getters such that users of the class can ask for things like "gimme your data so I can do soemthing with it", rather make them ask for "do something"

Comment: @user463035818 While I agree with you that getters are not flawless, and I would even dare to say that the core idea of encapsulation is simply lame, the imperfections of the design and core ideas of OOP are not what the question was about. However, getters for private members, if in a reasonable amount, are, after all, a common practice. And, as means for read-only access to private members from outside the class, getters work just fine, while they also allow us to adhere to some principles of OOP at the same time.

Comment: yeah sorry for going offtopic, the question was kind of settled so I didnt feel it was adding too much distraction. You seem to have made peace with something I am still struggling with ;). I still get excited by ppl mechanically writing getters and setters for everything and believing that would be what OOP is about

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you think will happen in this case?

```
TYPE t = DOUBLE;
if (rand() % 2 == 0) {
    t = INT;
}

int i = foo.get<int>(t); // t might be INT or DOUBLE
```

It cannot make sense, since the `TYPE` parameter is a runtime value, and you rely on it to choose the return type, which must be known at compile time.

Also, when you do the `switch` statement, the compiler *has* to compile the whole switch statement, even the cases that might not be invoked.

Imagine the `get<int>` member function being instantiated:

```
template<>
auto get<int>(TYPE type) -> int {
    switch (type) { // type might be anything
    case INT:
        return i;   // return int
    case DOUBLE:
        return d;   // return double
    case DOUBLE2:
        return d2;  // return double
    case STRING:
        return s;   // return string
    }
}
```

This cannot compile. The function clearly return an `int`, yet in some branch it returns other types.

A proper solution would be to drop the enum completely and use something like `constexpr if` to denote a compile time branch, and instead of sending both a typename and a value, rely only on the typename.

If you want to learn more about how to implement that kind of data structure, I suggest you go read about [`std::tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple)

Comment: @Chriss555888 implementing a tuple like structure is quite tricky but enlightening. It shows the complexity of implementing something actually simple